# Power of 2? whats wrong in code

Tags: java, list

If a given no is power of 2 then add 1 to list, if not power of two add 0 to list.
if given input list is [2,3,4]-->[1,0,1] should be the result, but i am getting [1,0,1,1] why?

here is my code

```
public class HelloWorld{
    public static void main(String []args){
        List<Integer> l=new ArrayList();
        l.add(2);
        l.add(3);
        l.add(4);


        List<Integer> l1=new ArrayList();

        for(int i=0;i<l.size();i++){
            if(l.get(i)==0)
                l1.add(0);

            int n=l.get(i);

            while(n!=1){
                if(n%2!=0){
                    l1.add(0);
                }
                n=n/2;
            }
            l1.add(1);

        }
        System.out.println(l1);
    }
```

Comment: Because 4 is 2 times 2. So 4%2=0, then 4/2 = 2, and  2%2=0

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your best bet here is to step through the code with the debugger built into your IDE, seeing exactly how the logic you've written works step-by-step. Learning to use a debugger is a **vital** skill for a beginning programmer, and don't worry, it's not complicated. *(not my downvote)*

Comment: Please see [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Try breaking from your loop after adding `0` to the list.

Comment: Side note: You don't need that `while` loop at all, you're overcomplicating things. :-) Happy coding!

Comment: In case it helps, `n > 0 && (n&-n)==n` will identify powers of 2.

Answer (score 0):

Your code breaks down at number 3, see what happens:

```
                        // first iteration                     second iteration
while(n!=1){            // 3 is not 1                          n is 1, so stop
    if(n%2!=0){         // 3%2 is 1, so it is not 0
        l1.add(0);      // you add 0 to the list
    }
    n=n/2;              // 3/2 is 1
}
l1.add(1);              //                                     after the loop, add 1
```

You don't want to add 1 if you've already added 0 for a number. You should make sure you only add one number to your new list for every number on your old list.

First, you might notice that Javac complains you're using unchecked or unsafe operations. That's because you're only using the <> diamond operators on one side. Add them to the right as well, to make sure the compiler know which objects can go in your list.

```
while(n!=1){            // As long as n is not 1
    if (n%2!=0){        // if n%2 is not 0 (it is 1) and we can
        l1.add(0);      //  set 0
    }
    if (n==2){          // if n is 2, it is a power of 2 and we can
        l1.add(1);      //  set 1
    }
    n=n/2;              // if n is neither 1, nor 2, we need to keep dividing
}
```

What you should do is only add 1 to your list if n is 2, because then you're sure the number you're working on is a power of 2.

Hopefully this is clear, because your next step will be fixing your code for when your list element is 0, because at the moment, that will result in an infinite loop. Good luck!